# Cron не запускает скрипт правильно

Tags: bash, cron

У меня есть простой скрипт для бэкапа. Скрипт отлично работает, когда я запускаю его вручную, но когда я пытаюсь запустить его через cron, он работает неправильно. Используя `echo` обнаружил, что проблема находится в строке `role_type=$(head -1 $ role)`. После этой строки следует `echo $role_type`, а при запуске вручную я вижу то, что ожидаю, но при запуске скрипта через cron он ничего не выводит.

Comment: А можно полный листинг?

Comment: Поставьте первой командой `env` и сравните вывод из-под `cron` и так.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо, помогло. Были разные pwd, нужно было перейти в нужный каталог перед исполнением